# How can I iterate through an array in a collection from firestore?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angularfire

I have some data in the console returned from firestore. I am trying to loop the comments array. 
[image]

HTML

```
  <div style="margin-top: 10px !important;" >   
       <p>{{item.comments[0]}}</p>
  </div>
```

ts 
      item: any;

```
 comments: any = [];
 comment: string;


  getData(){
    this.route.data.subscribe(routeData => {
     let data = routeData['data'];
     if (data) {
       this.item = data;
       this.image = this.item.image;  
       console.log(this.item) 
     }
    })   
  }
```

I have tried *ngFor="let item of item" in the html but it gives me an error saying "ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'"

Comment: What if you do `*ngFor="let comment of item.comments"` in the HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

What if you do `*ngFor="let comment of item.comments"` in the HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, you are actually trying to loop over `item`. What you want is to loop through `comments` in `item`.

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of item.comments">
    <pre> {{ comment | json }} </pre>
</div>
```